# Convert File to String array

Tags: android, string, file

I want to list a names of the files and put them into String array. To list a names of the files I'm using this code:

```
File dir = new File("/sdcard/Images/1124/");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i){
   Log.i(String.valueOf(files[i].getName()),"files");
}
```

I want to get something like that but with automatic values of files[i]:

```
String[] files = new String[] { "/sdcard/Images/1124/pic.jpg","/sdcard/Images/1124/pic2.jpg" };
```

So how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't your code work? What ìs the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
String[] fileArray;
File dir = new File("/sdcard/Images/1124/");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
fileArray = new String[files.length];
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i){
fileArray[i] = files[i].getName();
}
```